# Oracle query. Problem getting the exact time

Tags: oracle

I'm new to Oracle.
I had this report that will tag if it is or not complaint during time of generating the report.
The cutoff is Monday 2pm and asked to reached to 11am.
My problem is I don't know the exact number for this line to be on 11am exact.
(transaction date - TO_DATE(TRUNC(SCHEDULED_COMPLETION_DATE - 1,'D'))) >= 8.589

```
(
            CASE 
              WHEN (sysdate - TO_DATE(TRUNC(SCHEDULED_COMPLETION_DATE - 1,'D'))) >= 8.589 and ACTUAL_END_DATE is null  THEN 'NON-COMPLIANT'
              WHEN TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SCHEDULED_COMPLETION_DATE,'YYYY') || TO_CHAR(SCHEDULED_COMPLETION_DATE,'iw')) <> TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(ACTUAL_END_DATE,'YYYY') || TO_CHAR(ACTUAL_END_DATE,'iw'))
              and ACTUAL_END_DATE is not null THEN 'NON-COMPLIANT'
              WHEN 
              (transaction_date - TO_DATE(TRUNC(SCHEDULED_COMPLETION_DATE - 1,'D'))) >= 8.589 
              and ACTUAL_END_DATE is not null THEN 'NON-COMPLIANT'
              WHEN RECONCILIATION in ('MISSED(PM)', 'CANCELLED')THEN 'NON-COMPLIANT'
              ELSE
              'COMPLIANT'
            END
        ) AS REMARKS
```

Please help

reschedule from Monday 2pm to Monday 11am.

Comment: 8.589 isn't Monday 2pm - you aren't restricting to Monday, it's just a period of 8 days 14 hours 8 minutes 10 seconds, so 14:08:10 not 14:00:00. Date subtraction gives multiples of a day, so you could compare with `8 + 14/24`, and change that to `8 + 11/24`; or use an interval. But why 8 days, why are you calling `to_date()` for something that is already a date, why are you mixing ISO IW with non-ISO YYYY, and where does Monday fit in? Maybe break it down into an English description of the rules you need to apply and then figure out how to translate those to SQL logic?

Comment: You may use `to_char(dt, 'hh24mi')` to get time values that may be correctly ordered inside a single day